# Fix width to 50/50 in a splitpane made from FluentUI Stack component

Tags: office-ui-fabric, fluent-ui

I am using a stack component to make a split pane. I wanted to make it such that left side has 50% screen space and right side has the remaining 50%. However the problem is that the 2 panes are not equal width from beginning, and as text is added to the left component it starts to grow in width.

How do i fix this so that they always share width equally (50%/50%) ?

Here is a CSB illustrating the issue:

https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-faraday-lek5h?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: any luck with this? I am having the same issue